# スクロール禁止中のスクロール判定について

Tags: javascript

html,bodyをoverflow: hiddenにしたり等で、スクロールできない状態のときにスクロールしようとした場合に何らかの処理を行う。ということは可能ですか？

また、可能でしたらソースコードで教えて欲しいです。。
お願いしますm(_ _)m

Answer (score 3):

後述の例を少し変えればできると思います
このスニペットを実行するとスクロールするとalertが表示され、文面も変わります。

```js
var message = document.getElementById("message");
document.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  message.textContent = "スクロールしないでください";
  alert("スクロールは禁止されています");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="message">スクロール</p>
</body>
</html>
```